# no module named cntk

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

```
from __future__ import print_function # Use a function definition from future version (say 3.x from 2.7 interpreter)
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import os

import cntk as C

%matplotlib inline
```

And I get the error :

> `no module named cntk`

Comment: did you `pip install cntk` ? or `conda install cntk` if you are using Anaconda. And also make sure you install it for the specific virtual environment.

Comment: I recognised i haven't installed cntk. How to install cntk in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From whatever terminal you are starting your jupyter notebook. Type `pip install cntk` in that terminal. Then start your jupyter notebook from the same.

If in case you are using anaconda environments. Start the terminal of that virtual environment, your prompt should now say `(yourenv)username:` then install by running the same `pip install cntk` or if it's available in `conda` distributions use `conda install cntk`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this , hope that will solve your problem.

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev libopencv-dev python3-opencv python-opencv && ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so.1 && ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.12 && ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.12 && pip install cntk
```