# Whenever i am trying to import cntk it is showing No module named 'cntk._cntk_py'

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python 3.6 and I have already installed cntk=2.3. But whenever I tried to import it it is showing the following problems.

No module named 'cntk._cntk_py'

and at the end, it also shows some error like this

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: libmpi_cxx.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

please help. Thanks

Comment: please be clear in your question. What code are you running, whats the issue and what can others help you with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no module named cntk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316927/no-module-named-cntk)

Comment: I have already installed cntk-2.3 , but the problem is whenever i try to import cntk it shows No module named 'cntk._cntk_py' and the errors that are given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after running this command my problem solved.

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev libopencv-dev python3-opencv python-opencv && ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so.1 && ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.12 && ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.12 && pip install cntk
```